# Call Django template tag with userinput

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to use a Django custom template tag for checking whether the user id is in the database or not. We already created a custom template tag which works so far, but I can't get it to work with the form.

Goal is to not refresh the entire page but just show the result of this query. How is it possible to achieve this?

HTML Form:

```
<form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text">
    <button>Check Me</button>
</form>

{{ test|testid:123 }} <!-- Works, shows True or False -->
```

Filter:

```
@register.filter
def testid(value, test_id):
    if Test.objects.filter(id=test_id).exists():
        return True
    return False
```

I tried to look this up, but it seems that most of the people do this by implementing iQuery, just using forms or something similar and I'm trying to avoid this and wanted to use the template tag for this.

Comment: You can write one more function and call that function using ajax. ajax loaded with out page refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django is a back-end system only. Its involvement ends at the html template layer, i.e. it does not provide anything real-time. By default, all interactions involve a round-trip to the server, i.e. a page refresh. That doesn't mean you can't do real-time Ajax interactions in a Django project, only that Django isn't going to help you there and you're not going to find anything to help in the Django docs.

It requires a lot more work to produce these results without a page refresh. In most cases, I think people are overly enamored of accomplishing that goal. You're going to need to set up a receiving view, write javascript or jquery to post to the receiving view, save the data in the receiving view, and also write js to update the page in real time assuming that the back-end save went well. All possible and we've all done it, but do consider whether it's worth it.

If it's an absolute requirement, dig in, because it's going to require a fair bit of custom code and tooling.

Comment: You are probably right. I still was hoping to get something to work, but decided finally to use a separate view for the check and result.